# Windows 10 Pro and Docker service -- is it possible to start the Docker service later?

Tags: docker, windows-10

The problem I face is that the first time the Docker service on my Windows 10 pro computer is started at boot time, then I get all kinds of errors. Restarting the Docker service solves always the problem.

On my Windows 10 pro computer the Docker Service is started automatically. The problem is that the service starts a bit too early. I know about the Windows Fastboot but changing that I find to heavy to configure that to solve this problem.

Is there a way to configure the Docker service to start later in the Windows 10 boot sequence?

You think - make it a program that is started automatically. When I configure Docker NOT as a service, then I get all kinds of problems. The Docker system tray icon sometimes even gets the red color ...

The error messages are:

> ERROR: for docker-compose_geosolschmea_1  Cannot start service
>   geosolschmea: driver failed programming external connectivity on
>   endpoint docker-compose_geosolschmea_1
>   (3c0302743b124c050334b9ca3fcd3c9b01a0bcfaa1d629d74f7311cb09a58833):
>   Error starting userland proxy: mkdir
>   /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:3306:tcp:172.18.0.2:3306: inpuStarting
>   docker-compose_jenkins_1      ... error
>
> ERROR: for docker-compose_jenkins_1  Cannot start service jenkins:
>   driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint
>   docker-compose_jenkins_1
>   (fa039afd6930afba9843b89295e1bbeab32102679964780f867df1cd13282fe0):
>   Error starting userland proxy: mkdir
>   /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8888:tcp:172.18.0.3:8080: input/output error

Comment: Would it work if you disable Docker from startup apps on Task Manager -> startup ?
Configuring it to start later would require advanced knowledge on windows and docker itself. Very time consuming i think.

Comment: Please elaborate. The docker is started from a service.